# RAdwords Not working

Tags: r, google-ads-api

I am using `RAdwords` package to export the data from Google Adwords. Below is the code I am running and the error I am getting.

```
body <- statement(select=c('Clicks','AveragePosition','Cost','Ctr'),
                  report="ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT",
                  start="20150101",
                  end="20151231")
data <- getData(clientCustomerId="XXX-XXX-XXXX",
                google_auth=google_auth,
                statement=body)
Error in if (data[nrow(data), 1] == "Total") { : 
  argument is of length zero
```

Comment: I am getting the same error too! I have a quick query! Is the client customer ID is of manager account or linked account ? Let us say I have linked another adwords account to my manager account ?

Comment: Client Customer ID is the ID of the AdWords Account that you want to pull data from. I guess in your case this would be the linked account.
I have published a detailed package documentation here: http://jburkhardt.github.io/RAdwords/

Comment: Please report bugs related to the R RAdwords package at: https://github.com/jburkhardt/RAdwords/issues

Answer (score 0):

It seems like maybe you're having an issue that's not tracked well by the error that's thrown. I had a similar issue and it turned out that I didn't have the correct level of access needed with my developer token. You may need to work with your team to get access to a developer token with at least basic access in order to access client information through your MCC using RAdwords. Test account access is not enough to access client data.